# Asterisk and isdn phone: can "receive" calls, but outgoing calls are not seen by asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have configured a b410p isdn card with four NT ports. On the 4th NT port i put a TA which is on Windows os, and run an old isdn phone software(rvs phone).
I have configured the extensions.conf file like this

```
[from-dahdi]
exten => 084766508,1,Dial(DAHDI/g14/${EXTEN})
exten => 084766508,2,Hangup()
exten => _039.,1,Dial(DAHDI/4/${EXTEN})
```

If from console i call the 084766508 number the phone ring(but if I answer the call fail with 3302 isdn error), but if I call from the isdn phone a test number (200 for example)
the software phone put the 039 prefix, so I wrote the extension _039.
The problem is the outgoing call is not seen by asterisk, i also write

```
pri set debug on span 4
```

but report nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, I forgot to said the Windows was a virtual machine, If I redirect the usb TA adapter with usb redirection works very bad, can receive but not send the packets, if I put a pci-e usb adapter and redirect it(vfio pci-e redirect) then I connect the usb TA to it, works perfect: can answer, can call, can send packets.